# Remove Input="color" inner box border

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I remove the Inner Color Box of the color Input? I have tried these CSS properties

```css
input {
  border: none;
  /* background: none; */
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: none;
  appearance: none;
  color: white;
  border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body id="gradient">
  <h1>Background Generator</h1>

  <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
  <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#A569BD">
  <input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#00FFAE">
  <h3></h3>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: I'm in safari, and the inputs have no border.

Comment: @0stone0 Yes -webkit-color-swatch { border: none } Works. thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Run_Script strange